# How do I print out a char value for in an int array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, char, int

I am making a program with a two dimensional array and wherever there is the number -1, I would like out the program to print out C. This is what I have right now.

```
for (int[] arr : twoDimensionArray) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                            if (arr[i] == -1) {
                                arr[i] = 'C';
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int[] arr : twoDimensionArray) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                            if (arr[i] == -1) {
                                arr[i] = 'C';
                            }
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                            System.out.print((char)arr[i] + " ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
```

Comment: This prints out C but doesnt print out any of the other numbers

Comment: You haven't included any information about other content in the array or how you would like it to be printed

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int[][] twoDimensionArray = { { -1, 'b'}, { 'c', 'd' } };

    for (int[] arr : twoDimensionArray) {                       
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == -1) {
                arr[i] = 'C';
            }
        }

        System.out.println( intArrayToString(arr) );
    }
}


private static String intArrayToString(int[] arr){
    String str = "";

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        str += String.copyValueOf( Character.toChars(arr[i]) );
    }

    return str;
}
```